# Installing Elasticsarch - The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: windows, batch-file, elasticsearch, command-prompt

I'm trying to install ElasticSearch 5.x on my Windows7 machine

I go into the bin folder and issue the following command:

> elasticsearch-service.bat install elasticsearch-service
>   "C:\elasticsearch\jre"

Unfortunately I get:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

[image]

No idea why, the script seems to fail at the IF test (I tried printing some text before and after it)

```
IF NOT EXIST %JAVA% (

  ECHO Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME 1>&2
  EXIT /B 1
)
```

Comment: usage `elasticsearch-service.bat install|remove|start|stop|manager [SERVICE_ID]`

Comment: I have my own jre on a custom directory, how can I tell the script where it is located?

Comment: I still get "The syntax of the command is incorrect" even if I follow that usage

Comment: have you tried `elasticsearch-service.bat install`

Comment: yes, got the same. Elasticsearch version is 5.5.1

Comment: have you set your `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: no, but the script is supposed to work anyway, if you look at the script you'll see the line before deals with it, if JAVA_HOME is not set then it will set it for me